# What's the best practice to store oauth keys in my database?

Tags: mysql, oauth, twitter-oauth

I need to store `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` keys in an MySQL database. I can store those in two separate VARCHAR(90) fields but I see no use of keeping them separately. Is it smart to store them in one field as a serialized array? In that way I only need to provide one field for each network: LinkedIn, Twitter, Facebook,...

Comment: Where's the "exact duplicate"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store credentials for multiple sites that all require a token/secret pair, it seems more convenient to store them separately. This prevents you from making mistakes when un-serializing them. Besides that, there is little difference.